# Get input value in a variable in Angularjs before submit to call a webapi

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to access the input field value inside a variable that could be used in AngularJS so that I could add it to a string with the help of which I could call a rest api.

kindly help.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="myCtr">
       <form  name="myForm">
           <input type="text" ng-model='pinCode'  id="zip" onBlur="myZipcode">
           {{city}}
           {{state}}
       </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    var zip;
    var pat1;
      function myZipcode(){
           zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
           pat1 = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/'+zip;   
      }
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp' , []);
    myApp.controller('myCtr', function($scope, $http){
        var path = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/12345'  
        $http.get(pat1).success(function (response) {
        $scope.city = response.city;
        $scope.state = response.state;});    
    });
  </script> 
</body>
```

Here in http.get service if I use path variable instead of pat1 it works.
Another thing that I want the state and city to come dynamically without the form to be submitted and to be called from an REST API. That is why I am trying to get the input value inside a variable to accomplish the task

Comment: `onBlur="myZipcode"`, what does  you wanted to do there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to define extra var for `pinCode` because of you used `ng-model` so you can access `pinCode` from your controller. Also should use `ng-blur` instead of `onBlur`.

You can use like

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='pinCode'  id="zip" ng-blur="myZipcode()">
```

Controller:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp' , []);
    myApp.controller('myCtr', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.pinCode= ''; // defaulr empty
            var path = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/';
            $scope. myZipcode = function() {
                $http.get(path + $scope.pinCode).success(function (response) {
                   $scope.city = response.city;
                   $scope.state = response.state;
                }); 
            };  
        });
```

Comment: You are welcome and  you can accept this ans and vote up

Answer (score 0):

just bind `zip` and `pat1` on controller's scope

**Controller:**

```
myApp.controller('myCtr', function($scope, $http){
     $scope.zip = document.getElementById("zip").value || 0;
     $scope. pat1 = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/'+ $scope.zip || ''; 
     $scope.myZipcode();  
});
```

and then in zipcode

**Zipcode function:**

```
    $scope.myZipcode = function myZipcode(){
       $scope,zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
       $scop.pat1 = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/'+zip; 
    $http.get(pat1).success(function (response) {
    $scope.city = response.city;
    $scope.state = response.state;}

  }
```

**Complete code:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="myCtr">
       <form  name="myForm">
           <input type="text" ng-model='pinCode'  id="zip" ng-blur="myZipcode">
           {{city}}
           {{state}}
       </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    myApp.controller('myCtr', function($scope, $http){
         $scope.zip = document.getElementById("zip").value || 0;
         $scope. pat1 = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/'+ $scope.zip || ''; 
         $scope.myZipcode();  

  $scope.myZipcode = function myZipcode(){
         $scope,zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
         $scop.pat1 = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/'+zip; 
        $http.get(pat1).success(function (response) {
            $scope.city = response.city;
            $scope.state = response.state;}

           }
    });
  </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: why `onBlur` on input field?

Comment: @PankajParkar OP used it

Comment: I don't think it has any meaning there, as OP trying to access scope using JavaScript native functions. What do you say about it?

Comment: @PankajParkar changed it to ng-blur. i dont know what he is trying to do on blur but it seems that OP is trying to make http req on blur..

Answer (score 0):

You should not access html elements from your controller code. Angular's two way data-binding already transfers the form input's value into the `$scope.pinCode` variable. So you only need some action to trigger your server call. See this sample in the angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

```
myApp.controller('myCtr', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.doCall = function() {
         // $scope.pinCode() is set here
         $scope.$http.get(...).then(
             function(response) {
                 $scope.city = response.data.city; // or similar
             }
         );
    }
});
```